# What is the size of this Jacobian?

Tags: jacobian

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be given by
>   $f(r,s,t)=(r^{3}s+t^{2},rst)$.  Let $g:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{11}$
>   and $h:\mathbb{R}^{11}\to\mathbb{R}^{4}$ be two differentiable functions.
>   Compute
>   $$
>     J_{h\circ g\circ f}(0,21,0).
>   $$

I have the above question which I solved to be a zero matrix so not asking anyone to solve the question for me, however I do want to ask what the size of the resulting Jacobian matrix would be for this question?

Comment: What are the domain and range of the function $h\circ g\circ f$? The Jacobian gives the best linear approximation of that function, so it will map $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ when $h\circ g\circ f$ does.

Comment: So does that mean it will be 2x4?

Comment: No. You need to understand functions and also how matrices give you linear maps.

Answer (score 1):

The Jacobian of any differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ has dimensions $m\times n$, so determine just determine the $m,n$ values for the composite function $h\circ g\circ f$.